# How would you describe grabbing the hem of a skirt so you could carry something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How would you describe grabbing the hem of a skirt so you could carry something? I hope it's clear what I am getting at.

For example, you are wearing a skirt, or apron, and sitting down with something in your lap. You want to stand up and walk away carrying the items on your lap. You could grab the hem of the skirt to create a pouch-like place to carry the items in the skirt while you walk.

How would you describe that better than I have?

Using the picture **sumelic** linked, and the suggestion by **Mathieu K**, what would be best for the bolded word in the example below?

*Example*:

> Sally _________ [**gathered**] apples in her skirt and headed home to make a pie.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I mean, just didn't know a better way to describe it. That's where you come in.

Comment: Maybe the best you can do is what they say in the caption, "carrying in the skirt", but don't want to give the impression there are pockets

Comment: I think traditionally it's been 'gathering __ in her skirt' where the items in question are usually plural—if it were just one thing, why wouldn't you just carry it with your hands?

Comment: Well, that was just an example of carrying something, but I do mean multiple items, like apples in the picture, or a bunch of eggs.

Comment: No one likes downvotes, but I think adding the picture and an example makes it a better question, especially since I didn't know exactly how to ask it from the start. Thanks.

Comment: The picture in the link is described as "little girl clutching apples [...]". Clutching is what came to mind, although it has an air of awkwardness about it that might not be what you want. Otherwise, we'd just say fetchin' or totin' apples.

Comment: ...raising the hem of her skirt to make a pouch for carrying apples? Though eager to know one word for this..

Comment: @Phil Sweet I like your "clutching", but if you were trying to avoid implying grasp or awkwardness, you could use "cradling." Truth is, I think there must be some word whose meaning is in between these two words.

Comment: @Phil Sweet - It actually says, "clutching them to her chest", but I am asking about the "carrying apples in her skirt" part.

Comment: She placed the apples on her lap, lifted her skirt and carried the apples home.( ? ) I don't think there is a word that can substitute that action.

Comment: Maybe "cradled" the apples in her skirt?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is correct grammar (or even a word) but you could say something like. "The girl hammocked the apples in her skirt"

Comment: I understanding your meaning, but had to think on it a moment before I got the gist, and couldn't find any examples of that use anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that we can use the word ***pouched*** in this sense.

> Sally ***pouched*** apples in her skirt and headed home to make a pie.

Collins:

> **[pouch](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pouch)**
>   *verb*
>   **6**. (transitive) **to place** in or **as if in a pouch**
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers